# double linked list to implement a palindrome checker

Tags: java, linked-list, char, palindrome

Hi im trying to implement this code to check for palindrome and remove and add to left and right. im having trouble figuring out how to remove from the list and add please help.

```
public class DLL {

        private charNode DLLleft, DLLright;

         class charNode {
                 char data;
                 charNode left;
                 charNode right;

                public charNode(char D, charNode l, charNode r) {
                    data=D;
                    left = l;
                    right = r;
                }
         }  

        public DLL() {
            DLLleft= null;
            DLLright= null;
        }
        public void addDLLleft(char data){
            charNode temp = new charNode(data, null, DLLleft);
            if(DLLleft ==null)
                DLLright = temp;
            else
                DLLleft.left=temp;
                DLLleft = temp;
        }
        public void addDLLright(char data){
            charNode temp = new charNode(data, null, DLLright);
            if(DLLright == null)
                DLLleft = temp;
            else
                DLLright.right = temp;
                DLLright = temp;
        }
        public char removeDLLright(char data){
            charNode temp = DLLright;
            while (data == DLLright.data);

        }
        public void printRtoL(){
            charNode temp = DLLright;
            while(temp != null){
                System.out.println(temp.data);
                temp = temp.left;
            }
        }
        public void printLtoR(){
            charNode temp = DLLleft;
            while(temp != null){
                System.out.println(temp.data);
                temp = temp.right;
            }
        }
        public void clearDLL(){
            DLLleft = null;
            DLLright = null;
        }
    }
```

this is what i have so  far, but im stuck on how to remove from list and to check from palindrome .

Answer (score 1):

This would be super easy with one recursive method... However, let's have some fun. To make it more readable I'm going to rename some of your variables (I'll retain your method names so you know what's going on).

```
public class DLL<E> {

    private charNode head;
    private charNode tail;
    private int size;

    private class charNode {
             E element;
             charNode next;
             charNode prev;

            public charNode(E element, charNode next, charNode prev) {
                this.element = element;
                this.next = next;
                this.prev = prev;
            }
     }  

    public void addDLLleft(E element){
        charNode temp = new charNode(element, head, null);
        if(head != null ) {
          head.prev = temp;
        }
        head = temp;
        if(tail == null) {
          tail = temp;
        }
        size++;
    }
    public void addDLLright(char data){
        charNode temp = new charNode(element, null, tail);
        if(tail != null) {
          tail.next = temp;
        }
        tail = temp;
        if(head == null) {
          head = temp;
        }
        size++;
    }

    public E removeDLLleft(){
       if (size == 0) throw new NoSuchElementException();
       charNode temp = head;
       head = head.next;
       head.prev = null;
       size--;
       return temp.element;
    }

    public E removeDLLright(){
       if (size == 0) throw new NoSuchElementException();
       Node temp = tail;
       tail = tail.prev;
       tail.next = null;
       size--;
       return temp.element;

    }

    public void printRtoL(){
        charNode temp = tail;
        while(temp != null){
           System.out.println(temp.element);
           temp = temp.prev;
        }
    }

    public void printLtoR(){
       charNode temp = head;
       while(temp != null){
           System.out.println(temp.element);
           temp = temp.next;
       }
    }

    public void clearDLL(){
        DLLleft = null;
        DLLright = null;
    }

   // Necessary
   public int size() {
        return size;
   }
}
```